# Unable to patch Kiali configMap

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, patch, configmap

I have this Kiali configMap along with different Kiali resources like deployment, service etc all in a single yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.55.1
    app: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali
    version: "v1.55.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "v1.55.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: "kiali"
data:
  config.yaml: |
    external_services:
      custom_dashboards:
        enabled: true
      istio:
        root_namespace: istio-system
        config_map_name: istio-1-15-3
    auth:
      openid: {}
      openshift:
        client_id_prefix: kiali
      strategy: anonymous
    deployment:
      accessible_namespaces:
      - '**'
      additional_service_yaml: {}
      affinity:
        node: {}
        pod: {}
        pod_anti: {}
      configmap_annotations: {}
      custom_secrets: []
      host_aliases: []
      hpa:
        api_version: autoscaling/v2beta2
        spec: {}
      image_digest: ""
      image_name: quay.io/kiali/kiali
      image_pull_policy: Always
      image_pull_secrets: []
      image_version: v1.55
      ingress:
        additional_labels: {}
        class_name: nginx
        override_yaml:
          metadata: {}
      ingress_enabled: false
      instance_name: kiali
      logger:
        log_format: text
        log_level: info
        sampler_rate: "1"
        time_field_format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
      namespace: istio-system
      node_selector: {}
      pod_annotations: {}
      pod_labels:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      priority_class_name: ""
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
          memory: 64Mi
      secret_name: kiali
      service_annotations: {}
      service_type: ""
      tolerations: []
      version_label: v1.55.1
      view_only_mode: false
```

...

In this data I have to add this config under ***external-services***

```
data:
  config.yaml: |
    external_services:  
      prometheus:
         url: "http://prometheus-prometheus.observability-prisma.svc:9090/"
      custom_dashboards:
        enabled: true
      istio:
        root_namespace: istio-system
        config_map_name: istio-1-15-3
```

I have tried using following kubectl patches but no one is working
This patch is replacing the whole original data config part

```
kubectl patch configmap/kiali \                                                    
  -n istio-system \
  --type merge \
  -p '{"data":{"config.yaml":{"external_services":{"prometheus":{"url":"http://prometheus-prometheus.observability-prisma.svc:9090/"}}}}}'
```

This patch fails with the invalid request error. Since, the config under data is actually a string

```
kubectl patch cm kiali -n istio-system --type json --patch '[{ "op": "add", "path": "/data/config.yaml/external_services", "value": {"prometheus":{"url":"http://prometheus-prometheus.observability-prisma.svc:9090/"}} }]'
```

May I please get some assistance on how I can resolve this using kubectl or json-path function?

Answer (score 0):

The Kiali operator stores its deployment configuration in [Kiali CR(custom resource)](https://kiali.io/docs/installation/installation-guide/creating-updating-kiali-cr/), so if we create, update or remove a Kiali CR will trigger the Kiali operator to create, update or remove a Kiali. We cannot manually update a resource created by the Kiali operator, after you have created your Kiali CR you can manage your Kiali installation by using the below command

`kubectl edit kiali kiali -n istio-system`

Your Kiali CR can be validated by using the [Kiali CR validation tool](https://kiali.io/docs/configuration/kialis.kiali.io/#validating-your-kiali-cr).

Comment: @esahmo is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing the issue